# Display value if text strings from two ranges match

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have two worksheets in Excel. One contains the rankings:

[image]:

The other one the matchups (daily updated automatically)

[image]

The purpose is to display the rank of each respective team in two columns next to the matchups. One of the problems is that the text strings are not exact matches (limitation of the webquery).

So I need to find a formula for when there is a string of the table in Rankings that approximately matches the specified cell for the team in matchups *and* then display Rank (column 1 on Rankings) next to it.

So far I've got this in the cell where the ranking is supposed to go.

```
 =VLOOKUP("*"&qry!B5&"*";Sheet1!A3:C369;1;0)
```

But it just results in the string "rank" from the table header in Rankings.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things:

- Vlookup will try to find a match in the first column of the lookup table and can return a value from a column to the right. Your lookup table has the desired return value in the first column and the lookup values in the second column. Therefore, Vlookup will not work in this scenario. You can use a combination of Index and Match, though.
- the * wildcard before and after the lookup value mean that the value in the lookup table can have any text before and after the text already in your lookup value. In your case, the lookup value has more text than the text in the lookup table. So the wildcard is not helping.  Example: you have "353 Virginia" and you want to find this in a column that has only "Virginia". Wrapping "353 Virginia" in wildcards will add no value, because the text that you want to match is actually shorter than the text you are starting out with. You need to **remove** stuff from the lookup value instead of adding wild cards.

If the data for the rankings comes from a web query, you need to do some work to clean up that data, so it is fit for the lookup into your other table.

In addition to the number at the beginning, there are also two characters at the end of some cells that I cannot identify. These need to be stripped out, too, before you can do the lookup.

Assuming that all cells contain three digits and a space at the beginning you can use a formula approach

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B5;" @#";"");5;99))
```

Substitute will remove the trailing characters. I don't know what they are exactly, some web related special characters, so for the exercise here I have used `@#` instead of the A thing and the chevron. Copy and paste the web characters from one of your cells to the formula. With data coming from the web you may also want to check for leading and trailing white space, non-breaking space characters and other invisible characters.

You can use the "cleansing" formula as the basis of a lookup or, if the formula above sufficiently cleans the data, then you can use it in an index/match combo like this:

```
=index(Sheet1!$A$3:$A$369,match(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(B5;" @#";"");5;99));Sheet1!$B$3:$B$369;0))
```

Without seeing the actual data in a spreadsheet it is hard to tell if the formula cleanup is sufficient. You may need to do more work until a lookup returns the desired value.

If the data is coming from the web, I strongly suggest that you look into Power Query as a tool to get the data from the web into your spreadsheet. Power Query is a free add-in for Excel 2010 and 2013 and is built into Excl 2016 as "Get & Transform". It can connect to many data sources, including tables on a web page, and it has very powerful mechanisms to clean data for further processing. Once a Power Query is set up and working, all you need to do is refresh the query to load new data from the web site.

Comment: Hello, first off thank you for your response.
I've been able to get the first function working (TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE
and the data now displays without the weird symbols at the end or the numbers at the front.

However when I try to lookup the new "cleansed" value it still does not find it. I've tried linking both to the cleansed cell directly and using the formula you provided replacing  @ and # with the symbols required.

As you've mentioned this might be due to invisible characters. I've tried cleansing them further but it's not working yet.

looking into powerquery now to see if that helps

Comment: There is still an invisible space behind every string that I can't seem to get rid of.

Comment: So I tried cleansing for the white space behind with 'code' =TRIM(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(C5;CHAR(160);" "))) but still not working. Still returning #N/A.

Comment: So actually what I've found out is that Excel identiefies the string wrong.

When I Lookup a certain string for example Georgetown, Excel will pretend like I'm looking up Charlotte because for some reason it thinks it's a close match and will display a wrong ranking next to it (the one of charlotte instead of Georgetown). The thing is, it recognizes multiple cells as "Charlotte" with a lookup.

Comment: I got some of the values to work now through a VLOOKUP after extracting data from the other table and sorting it in the order needed for a VLOOKUP. It works for many of the teams now except a few that it still can not find.
 For example Sheet 1 there is CS Long Beach and on the other sheet it's named Long Beach St. Is there any way to fix that? If not i'll just have to deal with it. Thank you for your help, the cleansing of the text helped temendously. Could get the INDEX,MATCH To work but I'll keep trying . Thank you !

Comment: What is the exact formula you are using now? Vlookup or Match need a 0 or FALSE as the last parameter to perform an exact lookup.

Comment: I've got it solved so far; it's alot of manual input at the moment. Every name that has bits in it that aren't the same as the one it has to match with I just use SUBSTITUTE("xxx";"yyyy") I also made a new column with the ranking I need to the right of it so I can use VLOOKUP.
Thank you so much for your help !